# Where is the utility /usr/bin/line?

Tags: bash, scripts

Where is the 'line' utility gone that was in /usr/bin/line ?  I understand that the bash 'read' builtin is an alternative but I have many uses of line in shell scripts and don't like to touch all those. Maybe it is in a package not installed by default, but cannot find it. Thanks for hints.

Comment: [It was part of `util-linux`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fline), but doesn’t seem to be provided any more with 17.10+. :/

Comment: You could write your own script (something like `read line; echo $line`) and put that in `/usr/bin/line`. Then your scripts will work again.

Comment: @Jos It would be `IFS= read -r line; echo "$line"`. And it would be better to use `/usr/local/bin/line`, no?

Comment: Well, I tried to give a basic idea of a solution. But you are right on both accounts.

Comment: Probably a good way would be to make `util-linux` a dependency for your scripts, that is in the beginning of the script check if `util-linux` package is installed, and if not - run `apt-get install util-linux`. Alternatively, make your own "library" of functions, one of which would be what Jos and wjandrea suggested, and let your scripts source that library.  Besides, `read` is more portable - what if you need to use the scripts on  HP-UX or Aix or Solaris in future ? That is, make everything POSIX-compliant.